# Is there any way to generate grid classes for use directly on the markup

Tags: susy-compass

While I prefer to use the `susy` mixins on my css, in some cases it's useful to have general purpose grid classes, for example to use in webforms where it makes sense to have those declarations inline.

Any way to do that?

Currently I am generating those classes manually like so:

```
.grid-1{
    @include span-columns(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Grid classes would get very complex in a fluid system like Susy, because context is important. We don't provide it by default (yet). I whipped this up quick, and it should get you close:

```
@mixin susy-classes($silent: false) {
  $base: if($silent, '%', '.');
  $selector: '#{$base}span';

  @if $silent { #{$selector} { @include span-columns(1); } }
  @else { [class^="span-"] { @include span-columns(1); } }

  #{$base}full { clear: both; }
  #{$base}omega { @include omega; }

  @for $span from 1 through $total-columns {
    $span-selector: '#{$selector}-#{$span}';
    @for $context from 1 through $total-columns {
      $total-selector: '#{$span-selector}-#{$context}';
      $total-selector: if($context == $total-columns, '#{$span-selector}, #{$total-selector}', $total-selector);
      @if $context != $span {
        #{$total-selector} {
          @if $silent { @extend #{$selector}; }
          width: columns($span, $context);
        }
      } @else {
        #{$total-selector} { clear: both; }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include susy-classes;
```

That could get slightly cleaner if it were added to the Susy core, but for now it should cover your needs. It will output either silent classes to extend, or standard classes. Let me know how it works for you, and feel free to file an issue on github to consider moving this into the core.

Comment: Did this ever make it to susy core? I would also like the flexibility of susy with the option for grid classes where they make sense.

Comment: Not yet, no. But you could use this loop (for Susy 1) or write a loop of your own.

Comment: Thx, unfortunately I don't have your poetry skills :)

Comment: For the simplest use-case, you can trim it down a lot. See [this sassmeister demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9c82bfc25024e86bda03).